# Samsung galaxy s4 res folder

Tags: android

Is the samsung galaxy s4 screen density considered to be xxhdpi? or xhdpi?

From the galaxy specs the screen size is 1080 x 1920 pixels, 5.0 inches (~441 ppi pixel density).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try google before asking, loads of information  there. It's xxhdpi. Also if you're unsure create different pictures for the different res folders and test in emulator with same screen size and density;
http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.in/2013/03/how-to-develop-android-application-for.html

Comment: Just wanted to be sure it is xxhdpi

Comment: Some posts say that it picks it up from xhdpi!